# Store login access token into sharedpreference in android MVVM architecture

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, sharedpreferences, repository-pattern

currently i'm working with a real time api and in login api i got a access token in response. as i am following mvvm pattern i handle my datas by repositories. and i wants that the token i am getting from response will be stored in sharedpreference and later i will use it other api as header. and its not clear to me that how i can store that token into sharedpreference by repository.

My packages:

[image: mvvm architecture im using]

my repository class:

```
class OpusRepoImpl private constructor() : OpusRepository {

private val mLivedata: MutableLiveData<LoginPojo> = MutableLiveData()
private var rInstance: RetrofitInstance = RetrofitInstance()

override fun cLoginResponse(
    context: Context,
    username: String,
    password: String
): MutableLiveData<LoginPojo> {

    val apiServices = rInstance.getRetrofitInstance()?.create(ApiServices::class.java)
    val requestBody = LoginBody(username, password)

    val clientId = "myclientid"
    val clientSecret =
        "myClientSecrete"
    val grantType = "password"
    val call = apiServices?.getUser(clientId, clientSecret, grantType, requestBody)

    try {
        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginPojo> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<LoginPojo>,
                response: Response<LoginPojo>
            ) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    return
                }
                val loginResponse = response.body()
                loginResponse?.access_token

                //Here i want to save the login access token into sharedpreference

                mLivedata.postValue(loginResponse!!)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginPojo>, t: Throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        Toast.makeText(context, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return mLivedata
}

companion object {
    private var instance: OpusRepoImpl? = null

    fun getInstance(): OpusRepoImpl {
        return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
            instance ?: OpusRepoImpl().also { instance = it }
        }
    }
}
```

Login Fragment:

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment(), OnClickListener {


private lateinit var binding: FragmentLoginBinding

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentLoginBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}


override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    setOnclicklistener()
}

private fun setOnclicklistener() {
    binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this)
}

companion object {

    @JvmStatic
    fun newInstance() =
        LoginFragment().apply {
            arguments = Bundle().apply {

            }
        }
}

override fun onClick(v: View) {

    when (v.id) {
        R.id.btnLogin -> {
            val email = binding.edEmail.text.toString()
            val pass = binding.edPassword.text.toString()

            if (isValid()) {
                loginCheck(email, pass)
            }
        }

    }
}

private fun loginCheck(email: String, pass: String) {
    //val sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val loginViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[LoginViewModel::class.java]

    loginViewModel.loginResponse(requireContext(), email, pass).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { loginPojo ->

        val accessToken = loginPojo.access_token
        if (accessToken.isNotEmpty()){
            Navigation.findNavController(requireView()).navigate(R.id.homepage)
        }
    })
}

private fun isValid(): Boolean {

    binding.edEmail.error = null
    binding.edPassword.error = null

    var isValid = true
    val email = binding.edEmail.toString()
    val pass = binding.edPassword.toString()

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        isValid = false
        binding.edEmail.error = "Enter Your Email"
    } else {
        val emailPattern = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-z]+\\.+[a-z]+"
        if (!email.matches(emailPattern.toRegex())) {
            binding.edEmail.error = "Enter a Valid Email"
            isValid = false
        }
    }

    if (pass.isEmpty()) {
        isValid = false
        binding.edPassword.error = "Enter Your Password"
    } else {
        if (pass.length < 8) {
            binding.edPassword.error = "Your pass was at-least 8 character"
            isValid = false
        }
    }

    return isValid
}}
```

Login ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel(val application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

private val loginRepo = OpusRepoImpl.getInstance()

fun loginResponse(
    context:Context,
    username: String,
    password: String
): MutableLiveData<LoginPojo> {
    return loginRepo.cLoginResponse(context, username, password)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add this code :

```
 //For saveing access token in shared prefrence
 val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
 sharedPreferences.edit {
     putString("AccessToken", accesstoken)
      apply()
  }
```

this is the complete code :

```
class OpusRepoImpl private constructor() : OpusRepository {

    private val mLivedata: MutableLiveData<LoginPojo> = MutableLiveData()
    private var rInstance: RetrofitInstance = RetrofitInstance()

    override fun cLoginResponse(
        context: Context,
        username: String,
        password: String
    ): MutableLiveData<LoginPojo> {

        val apiServices = rInstance.getRetrofitInstance()?.create(ApiServices::class.java)
        val requestBody = LoginBody(username, password)

        val clientId = "myclientid"
        val clientSecret =
            "myClientSecrete"
        val grantType = "password"
        val call = apiServices?.getUser(clientId, clientSecret, grantType, requestBody)

        try {
            call?.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginPojo> {
                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<LoginPojo>,
                    response: Response<LoginPojo>
                ) {
                    if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        return
                    }
                    val loginResponse = response.body()
                    val accesstoken = loginResponse?.access_token
                    
                    
                    //For saveing access token in shared prefrence 
                    val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MySharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                    sharedPreferences.edit {
                        putString("AccessToken", accesstoken)
                        apply()
                    }

                    mLivedata.postValue(loginResponse!!)
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginPojo>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            Toast.makeText(context, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        return mLivedata
    }

    companion object {
        private var instance: OpusRepoImpl? = null

        fun getInstance(): OpusRepoImpl {
            return instance ?: synchronized(this) {
                instance ?: OpusRepoImpl().also { instance = it }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And also for getting access token from shared preference you can do this  :

```
val accessToken  = sharedPreferences.getString("AccessToken",null)
```

Right now I used the context which you are passing in function if it cause any issue you can pass the context in repository and use that context to initialize shared preference other alternative way is that you should use dependency injection for shared preference